# Access SYSTEM_POWER_STATE_CONTEXT from user-mode code

Tags: c++, hibernate, winapi, sleep, kernel32

I'm curious if there's a way (even if undocumented) to access [SYSTEM_POWER_STATE_CONTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj835780(v=vs.85).aspx) from a Windows local service written in C++ running in user-mode?

My goal is to distinguish between the system waking from sleep vs. hibernation, similar to what [they describe here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj835779(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do: is there a difference accessing the pw state ctx from a regular user  or LocalSystem?

Comment: @CristiFati: From LocalSystem

Comment: Again, is there a difference?

Comment: @CristiFati: the documented method for obtaining `SYSTEM_POWER_STATE_CONTEXT` only applies to device drivers.  You can't use it from a system service; if it is possible at all, it will require a different method.

Comment: Sorry, i was looking at MSDN.